# Python 3.* compilled for HP-UX ia64 (or depot)

Tags: python, hp-ux

Where can get depot (or just precompilled package) with Python 3.* or at least 2.6.* for ia64-hp-hpux11* ?

Packages for hppa64-hp-hpux11* (PA-RISC) can be found at [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads/) but not for Itanium.

I can't compile it by myself because of different HP-UX and ANSI-C related problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out the PA-RISC version. It should work but not as fast as a native Itanium binary. [Aries](http://docs.hp.com/en/5187-0701/ch08s07.html) will take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid the best packaged (depot) version you can currently find is 2.5.2.

There are two good sources for such packages:

- [software.hp.com](http://software.hp.com) (Look for "HPUX Internet Express")
- HP-UX Porting and Archiving Centre at http://hpux.connect.org.uk

Comment: Update: Looks like the package on software.hp.com ("HP-UX Internet Express" suite) has version 2.7.